# Same button id in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have face the problem on clicking button on Python Selenium with same id
I can Have two buttons in one page named 'Upload' and 'Generate Base Form' but the two buttons id is same.
I will select the Button named "Generate Base Form". The id of the Button is also same.
I will attach the image of inspector
[Image of Id for button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiRFt.png)

Comment: Update your ticket with `HTML` for both buttons, but not image. Also add a question as there is only issue description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's good practice to find elements by Id, Name or CssClass, in some cases you'll end up depending on more specific properties, so that you can exclusively locate the element. The most common solution is using XPath.

In your case, something like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='uploadButton' and @value='Upload']").click()
```

Should work. Notice that if the other button also has the same **value** attribute, you'll need to discover what's unique about the element you're trying to locate, and use it with XPath.

Alternatively, you could also do

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@id='uploadButton'])[buttonNumber]").click()
```

Where *buttonNumber* is an index that goes from 1 to n, accordingly to the number of buttons you have with that same id.

[This](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) article can help you with locating elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath

```
//input[@id='eRetVO.fileExtend']/../input[2]
```